# Merging two JSON objects with the same key into one key

Tags: json, powershell

I have two JSON files that I want to combine that may have the same key values in.

**file1.json**

```json
{
  "parentKey": {
    "secretkey1": "secretkey1value",
    "secretkey2": "secretkey2value"
  }
}
```

**file2.json**

```json
{
  "parentKey": {
    "settingKey1": "settingkey1value",
    "settingKey2": "settingkey2value"
  }
}
```

I want the output of the merged files to combine duplicate keys automatically without having to know which keys are duplicate in the code.

**expected-merged.json**

```json
{
  "parentKey": {
    "settingKey1": "settingkey1value",
    "settingKey2": "settingkey2value",
    "secretkey1":  "secretkey1value",
    "secretkey2":  "secretkey2value"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to cleanly achieve this with Powershell?

My attempt was this

```
$app1 = Get-Content -Path './app1.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$app2 = Get-Content -Path './app2.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

@($app1; $app2) | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File './merged.json'
```

However it outputs duplicated keys like so

```json
[
    {
        "parentKey":  {
                          "secretkey1":  "secretkey1value",
                          "secretkey2":  "secretkey2value"
                      }
    },
    {
        "parentKey":  {
                          "settingKey1":  "settingkey1value",
                          "settingKey2":  "settingkey2value"
                      }
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mind showing us your attempt at this?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I've updated the original post with my attempt

Comment: Where is the comparison to check if both Json have the same key values?

Comment: I wasn't sure if there was functions within PS to do this sort of thing automatically or simply. If not I can roll my own.

Answer (score 3):

Using your examples, you could do something like this:

```
$app1 = Get-Content -Path './app1.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$app2 = Get-Content -Path './app2.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($item in $app2.parentKey.PsObject.Properties) {
   $app1.parentKey | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $item.Name -Value $item.Value
}

$app1 | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path './merged.json'
```

Result:

```
{
    "parentKey":  {
                      "secretkey1":  "secretkey1value",
                      "secretkey2":  "secretkey2value",
                      "settingKey1":  "settingkey1value",
                      "settingKey2":  "settingkey2value"
                  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Theo! Thanks for the reply. This would work however the keys can be dynamic and I'm not always sure what the name of the key would be so I would need the approach to be able to handle any key name.

Comment: @Paradigm Yep, but I'll leave that for you to figure out. [1] At what level do you want to start the merge? [2] What to do with duplicate keys/values? My answer shows you how you can use `.PsObject.Properties` on an object to get its Name and Value. You can do the same on the `$app1` objects to get the key names in there. Next, try and find equal keynames in `$app2` and do the merge as shown.